# Interpolating a non-interpolated passed string inside a subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl

I am looking to parse a tab delimited text file into a nested hash with a subroutine. Each file row will be keyed by a unique id from a uid column(s), with the header row as nested keys. Which column(s) is(are) to become the uid changes (as sometimes there isn't a unique column, so the uid has to be a combination of columns). My issue is with the `$uid` variable, which I pass as a non-interpolated string. When I try to use it inside the subroutine in an interpolated way, it will only give me the non-interpolated value:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $lofrow = tablehash($lof_file, '$row{gene}', "transcript", "ENST");

    ##sub to generate table hash from file w/ headers
    ##input values are file, uid, header starter, row starter, max column number
    ##returns hash reference (deref it)
    sub tablehash   { 
        my ($file, $uid, $headstart, $rowstart, $colnum) = @_;
        if (!$colnum){ # takes care of a unknown number of columns
            $colnum = 0;
        }
        open(INA, $file) or die "failed to open $file, $!\n";
        my %table; # permanent hash table 
        my %row; # hash of column values for each row
        my @names = (); # column headers
        my @values = (); # line/row values
        while (chomp(my $line = <INA>)){ # reading lines for lof info
            if ($line =~ /^$headstart/){
                @names = split(/\t/, $line, $colnum);
            } elsif ($line =~ /^$rowstart/){ # splitting lof info columns into variables
                @values = split(/\t/, $line, $colnum);
                @row{@names} = @values;
                print qq($uid\t$row{gene}\n); # problem: prints "$row{gene} ACB1"
                $table{"$uid"} = { %row }; # puts row hash into permanent hash, but with $row{gene} key)
            }
        }
        close INA;
        return \%table;
    }
```

I am out of ideas. I could put `$table{$row{$uid}}` and simply pass `"gene"`, but in a couple of instances I want to have a `$uid` of `"$row{gene}|$row{rsid}"` producing `$table{ACB1|123456}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpolation is a feature of the Perl *parser*. When you write something like

```
"foo $bar baz"
```

, Perl compiles it into something like

```
'foo ' . $bar . ' $baz'
```

It does not interpret data at runtime.

What you have is a string where one of the characters happens to be `$` but that has no special effect.

---

There are at least two possible ways to do something like what you want. One of them is to use a function, not a string. (Which makes sense because interpolation really means concatenation at runtime, and the way to pass code around is to wrap it in a function.)

```
my $lofrow = tablehash($lof_file, sub { my ($row) = @_; $row->{gene} }, "transcript", "ENST");

sub tablehash   { 
    my ($file, $mkuid, $headstart, $rowstart, $colnum) = @_;    
    ...
                my $uid = $mkuid->(\%row);
                $table{$uid} = { %row };
```

Here `$mkuid` isn't a string but a reference to a function that (given a hash reference) returns a uid string. `tablehash` calls it, passing a reference to `%row` to it. You can then later change it to e.g.

```
my $lofrow = tablehash($lof_file, sub { my ($row) = @_; "$row->{gene}|$row->{rsid}" }, "transcript", "ENST");
```

---

Another solution is to use what amounts to a template string:

```
my $lofrow = tablehash($lof_file, "gene|rsid", "transcript", "ENST");

sub tablehash   { 
    my ($file, $uid_template, $headstart, $rowstart, $colnum) = @_;    
    ...
                (my $uid = $uid_template) =~ s/(\w+)/$row{$1}/g;
                $table{$uid} = { %row };
```

The `s///` code goes through the template string and manually replaces every word by the corresponding value from `%row`.

---

Random notes:

- Bonus points for using `strict` and `warnings`.
- `if (!$colnum) { $colnum = 0; }` can be simplified to `$colnum ||= 0;`.
- Use lexical variables instead of bareword filehandles. Barewords are effectively global variables (and syntactically awkward because they're not first-class citizens of the language).
- Always use the 3-argument form of open to avoid unexpected interpretation of the second argument.
- Include the name of your program in error messages (either explicitly with `$0` or implicitly by omitting `\n` from `die`).
- `my @foo = (); my %bar = ();` is redundant and can be simplified to `my @foo; my %bar;`. Arrays and hashes start out empty; overwriting them with an empty list is pointless.
- `chomp(my $line = <INA>)` will throw a warning when you reach EOF (because you're trying to chomp a variable containing `undef`).
- `my %row;` should probably be declared inside the loop. It looks like it's supposed to only contain values from the current line.

Suggestion:

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$0: can't open $file: $!\n";
while (my $line = readline $fh) {
    chomp $line;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the function worked perfectly. For the chomp, I tried to force it to give me a warning by adding extra newlines and it still didn't seem to have an issue, both with and without lexical file handles. is that just something that is a version difference (our server runs v5.10.1)?

Comment: @dragon951 Doesn't seem to be. I see the warning on 5.8.9, 5.10.1 and 5.24.1 using the following code: `perl -e 'use warnings; while (chomp(my $line = <>)) {}' /dev/null`